# "A mi lado" o "Al lado mío"

Tags: modismos, expresiones

Yo sé que lo más correcto es decir "a mi lado", pero en la región de donde vengo, es habitual decir "al lado mío". Ahora vivo en el extranjero y mucha gente se extraña de la expresión y me dicen que está mal. Si bien nadie me ha podido dar una explicación de por qué puede estar mal.

He visto que en este foro hay bastante gente muy versada, quizá alguien me pueda ayudar a aclarar esta duda.

P. D.: A veces también decimos "al lado mía", eso sí reconozco que es raro.

Comment: *al lado mía* es claramente incorrecto porque falla la concordancia de género entre el sustantivo *lado* y el adjetivo *mía*.

Comment: En algunas regiones del sur de España se utiliza incluso "a mi vera" o, más poéticamente "a la vera mía".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es correcto, [las FAQ de la RAE lo mencionan](https://www.rae.es/consultas-linguisticas/preguntas-frecuentes).

Véase la parte de  *Detrás de mí, encima de mí, al lado mío* del enlace anterior

Copio un fragmento que será útil:

> Para discernir si es o no correcta una expresión con posesivo, debemos fijarnos en la categoría de la palabra núcleo: si es un sustantivo, será correcta (puede decirse *al lado mío*, pues *lado* es un sustantivo); pero no será correcta si se trata de un adverbio (no puede decirse *cerca mío*, pues *cerca* es un adverbio).
>
> Para no equivocarse, resulta útil saber que si se puede usar el posesivo átono antepuesto, la construcción con el posesivo tónico pospuesto será también válida:
>
> *Estoy al lado de María > Estoy a su lado > Estoy al lado suyo (CORRECTO)*
>
> *Giraban alrededor de ti > Giraban a tu alrededor > Giraban alrededor tuyo (CORRECTO)*
>
> pero
>
> *Estoy detrás de María > *Estoy en su detrás > *Estoy detrás suyo/suya (INCORRECTO).*
>
> *Vive cerca de ti > *Vive en tu cerca > *Vive cerca tuyo/tuya (INCORRECTO).*
>
> Por último, es importante señalar que el posesivo pospuesto debe concordar en género con el sustantivo al que modifica; así pues, debe decirse *al lado suyo* (y no **al lado suya*), puesto que el sustantivo *lado* es masculino.

Si el primer enlace no funciona probad [este](http://www.google.com/search?q=Detr%C3%A1s%20de%20m%C3%AD,%20encima%20de%20m%C3%AD,%20al%20lado%20m%C3%ADo%20FAQ%20RAE&btnI).

Comment: Es *probar*, no *provar* :) (típico error de catalán bilingüe). Por lo demás, creo que la respuesta es perfecta. Aunque me gustaría añadir que a veces incluso este método lleva a error. Por ejemplo, es habitual oír *en mi contra* o *en contra mía*, pese a ser incorrecto; debe ser *en contra de mí* o, simplemente, *contra mí*.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: De nada. Es probar si :). Por cierto como contra es sustantivo femenino si es correcto el uso de *en contra mía*, también lo es *en mi contra*. [Definición número 5 de contra en la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=contra#5)

Comment: @AlexBcn Tienes toda la razón. Acabo de aprender algo, gracias por ello.